# Html javascript getattribute not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck on this for a while now and i don't know whats wrong.
My getAttribute is always returning undefined..
I've tried a lot ,i messed with value and classnames but it always returns undefined.
please help someone

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="resources/css/Home.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="floatleft">
    <img class="ploegen.html"  onclick="GoTo(this)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/ploegenhome.jpg">
    <img onclick="GoTo(x)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/stadionhome.jpg">
    <img  onclick="GoTo(x)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/opstellinghome.png">
    <img  onclick="GoTo(x)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/simulatiehome.jpg">
</div>
<img src="resources/logo_wk_2018.png" id="logowk">
<div id="tekstjes">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Ploegen</a></li>
        <li><a>Stadions</a></li>
        <li><a>Opstelling</a></li>
        <li><a>Simulatie</a></li>
    <ul/>
</div>
<p id="lol"></p>
<script>
    function GoTo(x){
       var y = x.getAttribute(className);
        document.getElementById("lol").innerText = y;

    }
    function leave(x){
        x.style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    function hover(x){

        x.style.opacity = 1;
        var y = x.getAttribute(className);
        document.getElementById("lol").innerText = y;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are passing in `className` variable to your `getAttribute` which is undefined...What class name do you want to get?

Comment: also, if `className` is not a variable, you should use `"className"`, with quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Error :

- The problem with your code is that there is no variable called `ClassName` in your code.
- Another thing that was wrong was that you were using `x` in your onClick function for goTo instead of `this`
- Another slight problem that I found when running the code was that in the end of your `<ul>` tag you used `<ul/>` instead of `</ul>` to close the tag.

## Fix :

```js
function GoTo(x){
   var y = x.getAttribute("class");
    document.getElementById("lol").innerText = y;

}
function leave(x){
    x.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
function hover(x){

    x.style.opacity = 1;
    var y = x.getAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById("lol").innerText = y;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="resources/css/Home.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="floatleft">
    <img class="ploegen.html"  onclick="GoTo(this)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/ploegenhome.jpg">
    <img onclick="GoTo(this)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/stadionhome.jpg">
    <img  onclick="GoTo(this)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/opstellinghome.png">
    <img  onclick="GoTo(this)" onmouseleave="leave(this)" onmouseover="hover(this)" src="resources/simulatiehome.jpg">
</div>
<img src="resources/logo_wk_2018.png" id="logowk">
<div id="tekstjes">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Ploegen</a></li>
        <li><a>Stadions</a></li>
        <li><a>Opstelling</a></li>
        <li><a>Simulatie</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p id="lol"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to @RogerC for who spotted a mistake in the code that I thought I had fixed :)